# A number is chosen by random from the set of natural numbers. what is the probability that number will be even?

Tags: probability-theory

I know that there is no answer to this question, but how to explain that the probability doesnt exist? I spent a lot of time reading answers to this question. Almost all people say that we cant define the probability because we cant choose a number uniformly in natural set. But what if we say that $P(n) = 2^{-n}$ where $n = \{1,2,3...\}$. Then there will be no contradictions with the axioms of the probability theory

Comment: Then you sum the [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) $\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-2k} = \frac{2^{-0}}{1-2^{-2}}$ and obtain the probability $1/3$.

Comment: But then , we have not what we would expect from a "random natural number" without any further context. Here, we can use a random number in the range $[1,n]$ and let $n$ tend to $\infty$. The probability to get an even number will tend to the intuitive $\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is not that one can't choose a natural number at random, it's that there are many different ways of doing so. When one is given a finite set $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ then there is a natural way to choose a number at random: uniformly. (This is by no means the only way to choose a number at random from a finite set.)

When the set is $\mathbb{N}$ it is not possible to choose a number uniformly in the sense that if $P(n=n_0)=x$ for all $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ then by additivity we have that $P(n\in\mathbb{N})=\infty>1$ which contradicts the axioms of probability.

So there are many ways to choose a random number from $\mathbb{N}$, but uniformly is not one of them. For each such probability distribution you choose you will get a different chance that the chosen number is even.